# Trying to use Multer

Tags: node.js, multer

Training myself to understand how work Multer with React. This is multer-config.js :

```
const multer = require("multer");

const MIME_TYPES = {
  "image/jpg": "jpg",
  "image/jpeg": "jpg",
  "image/png": "png",
};

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    console.log("oui");
    callback(null, "images");
  },

  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    const name = file.originalname.split(" ").join("_");
    const extension = MIME_TYPES[file.mimetype];
    callback(null, name + Date.now() + "." + extension);
  },
});

const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send("Something went wrong!");
};

module.exports = multer({ storage: storage }).single("image");
```

And this is the controller :

```
exports.createCommInfos = (req, res, next) => {
  const infosObject = req.body;
  const infos = new CommInfos({
    ...infosObject,
    imageUrl: `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/images/${
      req.body.picture.path
    }`,
  });

  infos
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      res.status(201).json({ message: " Infos enregistré !" + infos });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).json({ error });
    });
};
```

This is the function that I use to POST :

```
export async function postCommInfos(e, body, setCommPayment, setCommForm) {
    e.preventDefault(e);


      if (validForm(body)) {
        console.log(body)
            try {
      await fetch("http://localhost:8000/bioanimale/comminfos", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });
      setCommPayment(true)
      setCommForm(false)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
      }

  }
```

When I use a POST route, my database receive succesfully my data, but Multer is supposed to save the image in backend/images, but it doesn't work. The both console.log (in the controller and in multer-config.js) doest not appears at all when I use POST.

---

```
router.post("/cominfos", multer, infosCtrl.createComInfos);
router.post("/recinfos", multer, infosCtrl.createRecInfos);
router.post("/orainfos", multer, infosCtrl.createOraInfos);
```

```
const multer = require("../middleware/multer-config.js"); // This line is in my routes' file
```

Comment: Please show your route definition where you add multer as the middleware.

Comment: router.post("/cominfos", multer, infosCtrl.createComInfos);
router.post("/recinfos", multer, infosCtrl.createRecInfos);
router.post("/orainfos", multer, infosCtrl.createOraInfos);

Comment: Thanks for adding that. I've also added it to the question. Can you also show how you import/require the multer instance you export from your first file?

Comment: const multer = require("../middleware/multer-config.js");
This line is in my routes' file

const multer = require("multer");
This one is in multer-config.js

And multer is in my packages in package-lock.json
"packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "backend",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "mongoose": "^7.0.2",
        "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
        "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0"
      }